# How to make our app resolution free

Tags: java, android

We have to display many TextView on canvas with proportion to screen resolution.How we can define the textSize and any ImageView size corresponding to Screen resolution so that they can display ratio wise.

Answer (score 0):

Use for textSize and the dimensions of the ImageView dp intead of normal pixels px. dp are density indipendent pixels. It's an unit measure that will scale in a nice way with the screen proprieties of the device that is running the application.

Comment: What about AbsoluteFrame, if we are using in our app?