# How to make resolution free app

Tags: java, android

I have set 320x480 size for canvas/widget of app. How can I make it resolution free.I have to draw some tips on particular location using AbsoluteLayout.If I change size of canvas/widget then the tips are displaying at wrong coordinates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make our app resolution free.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263869/how-to-make-our-app-resolution-free)

Answer (score 3):

You should not work with absolute layout. Learn how to use other layout managers in Java. It can look complicated at the beginning but it's your only hope to get a resizable application without all the burden of managing size by yourself. Layout managers are precisely done to handle components positionning whatever the size of the container is.

The 3 basics layout managers are :

- BorderLayout
- GridLayout
- FlowLayout

A very usefull layout manager is BoxLayout (though the constructor is weird).

[Here is a good docs from SUN about layout managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

When you master this, and it's not so difficult, you can build almost any application in swing.

And if you work with custom components, I mean JPanel where you overrided paintComponent, then you should consider 2 options :

1. Not to scale at all for performance reasons,
2. Scale using AffineTransform on your graphics. But this is a different topics, your questions seemed more general about swing components.

Oh, and by the way, I think you should really accept answers from people and vote for what answer helped you. It's the minimal way to thank people here.

Comment: Droid does have differ resolution so how  can I fix and app resolution free.

Comment: Hello Kumar, the same applies for Android. You should then learn to use the different layout options : relative layout, linear layout and frame layouts are the basic layout managers for android. They will arrange all components sizes and positions for you. Here is a good starting point for android layout managers : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html